# Limiting returned records for an interaction in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-2

I have the following script that returns a list of all the customer names at that point when it is clicked on. I am looking to limit this to only show the first (or just one) record.Could this be achieved through a modification of the following?

```
   function customer(browserEvent) {
    var coordinate = browserEvent.coordinate;
    var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate);
    var el = document.getElementById('customer, single');
    el.innerHTML = '';
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
      el.innerHTML += feature.get('Proj_Client') + '<br>';
    });
  }
  map.on('pointerdown', customer);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the api [ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel)

If you put a return statement that should return only one object.

In your case:

```
var firstFeatureFound = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
  return feature;
});
el.innerHTML += firstFeatureFound.get('Proj_Client') + '<br>';
```